# Saving each step using a Contact Form 7 Multi Step Form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

I am using a multi step Contact Form 7, which I am able to save to a database upon submission. I am using the plugin from cf7addons.com.

When a logged in user selects the "next" button to move to the next stage of a form, I want to be able to save the data of the step they just completed, without submitting the form.

Is this possible ?

Comment: it is possible but you will need to write a custom js code to do so, triggered by the next button click event, capture the field values in that step and send them to the server by an AJAX call.  On the server side you will then need to save the data with a custom PHP function.  See this [tutorial](https://wpmudev.com/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/) for more details.

Comment: Aside from that, why do you want to save your fields at each steps?  Why not simply save what is submitted?